# How to add values across multiple nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm practicing some coding to learn how to add up a list of keys with values in multiple nested dictionaries. The final output is to produce a total count of "fruits" in the code. Is there a way to do so without having to break up the nested dictionaries into multiple separate dictionaries and use Counter from collections?

```
fruit_count = 0

not_fruit_count = 0

basket_items = {1: {'apples': 4, 'oranges': 19, 'kites': 3, 'sandwiches': 8},
    
            2: {'pears': 5, 'grapes': 19, 'kites': 3, 'sandwiches': 8, 'bananas': 4},

            3: {'peaches': 5, 'lettuce': 2, 'kites': 3, 'sandwiches': 8, 'pears': 4},

            4: {'lettuce': 2, 'kites': 3, 'sandwiches': 8, 'pears': 4, 'bears': 10}}

fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'peaches', 'grapes', 'bananas']


for item, value in combined.items():

    if item in fruits:

        fruit_count += value

    else:

        not_fruit_count += value


print("\nTotal fruit count: {}".format(fruit_count).title())

print("\nTotal non-fruit count: {}".format(not_fruit_count).title())
```

The expected result should give:

> Total fruit count: 64
>
> Total non-fruit count: 58

Comment: where is `combined` defined in your code and what is its value?

Comment: `for _, combined in basket_items.iteritems():\n    for item, value in combined.iteritems()` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
for item, value in basket_items.items():
  for k, v in value.items():
    if k in fruits:
      fruit_count += v
    else:
      not_fruit_count += v
```

Total Fruit Count: 64, 
Total Non-Fruit Count: 58

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit_count = sum(sum(basket.get(fruit, 0)
                      for basket in basket_items.values())
                  for fruit in fruits)
# OR
fruit_count = sum(sum(val
                      for key, val in basket.items()
                      if key in fruits)
                  for basket in basket_items.values())

non_fruit_count = sum(sum(val
                          for key, val in basket.items()
                          if key not in fruits)
                      for basket in basket_items.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for key, value in basket_items.items()
    if key in fruits:
        fruit_count += value
    else:
        not_fruit_count += value
print(fruit_count, not_fruit_count)
```